# c# zedgraph как задать названия осям и содержание заголовку?

Tags: c#, zedgraph

Используя библиотеку zedgraph нужно поменять название осей и содержание заголовка (подчеркнутые красным).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Искал как это сделать, сделал по примеру, но выдает ошибку ("string" не содержит определение для "Text". Не удалось найти метод  расширения "Text")
)

```
        GraphPane pane = Graph.GraphPane;

        pane.Title.Text = 'Графiк коливань згладжувального фiльтра';
        pane.XAxis.Title.Text = "V";
```

Поясните как задать собственные названия для осей и содержание заголовка в форме

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй
`pane.Title = "Графiк коливань згладжувального фiльтра";`
Видимо `pane.Title` - уже строка

Comment: Да, после обновления Zedgraph все поменялось, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

GraphPane pane =  SpectrAnalyzer.GraphPane;
pane.Title.Text = "Название графика";
pane.XAxis.Title.Text = "Название оси Х";
pane.YAxis.Title.Text = "Название оси У";